# Find $t$ in $N = b \times g^t$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

The problem is the following:

Find the value of $t$ in $N = b × g^t$.

So for example "$512.000 = 2000 × 2^t$"

I'm not really a mathematician so their may be a simple way or it could be hard.

Comment: I assume that on the left you have $512000$ (five hundred and twelve thousand). Then $2^t=\frac{512000}{2000}=256$. What $t$ is it such that $2^t=256$? To many, it will be clear that $t=8$. But suppose we had an uglier number than $256$, like $233$. We solve $2^t=233$ by taking the logarithm (any base, as long as we are consistent) of both sides. We get $t\log(2)=\log(233)$, so $t=\frac{\log(233)}{\log(2)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}
\rm N=b\cdot g^{\rm\displaystyle t}&\iff g^{\rm\displaystyle t}=\rm\dfrac Nb\\
&\iff\color{grey}{\boxed{\color{black}{\rm\, t=\log_{\rm\displaystyle g}\left(\rm \dfrac Nb\right)}}}
\end{align*}$$

where $\rm\log_{\rm\displaystyle g}$ is the logarithmic function to the base $\rm g$ which is basically the function that tells us for which number $x$, $b^x$ will give you $c$.

**Example:** $\rm 512\,000 = 2000 \times 2^t$. By our result, and by setting $\rm b=2000$, $\rm g=2$ and $\rm N=512\,000$, we have: $$\begin{align*}
\rm t &=\log_2\left(\dfrac{512\,000}{2000}\right)\\
&= \log_2(256)\\ &=8.
\end{align*}$$
You can even try it: $2000\times 2^8=2000 \times 256=512\,000$.

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.